# How to split a string and record each split as a distinct variable C++

Tags: c++, string

I was looking at a popular StackOverflow post about how to split strings.  I have found this very useful, but I'd like to take each split and store it in array or a distinct string variable.  Such that I can access: scott, tiger, mushroom, or fail.  Below is my attempt to do this, but I cannot complile this due to an error:

> cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'char' in assignment

Does anyone know an efficient way of doing this?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
     
char str[10];
void setup(){
    std::string s = "scott>=tiger>=mushroom>=fail";
    std::string delimiter = ">=";
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = s.substr(0, pos);
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
        s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        str[arrayIndex++] = token;
        
    }
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
    
void loop(){
}
```

Comment: Why not just use an exiting strsplit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str[]` is an array of individual `char`s, but you are trying to store `std::string` objects in it, hence the error. Change the array to hold `std::string` instead of `char`. And then consider using `std::vector` instead of a fixed array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
     
std::vector<std::string> str;

void setup(){
    std::string s = "scott>=tiger>=mushroom>=fail";
    std::string delimiter = ">=";
    
    size_t start = 0, pos;
    std::string token;

    while ((pos = s.find(delimiter, start)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = s.substr(start, pos-start);
        str.push_back(token);
        start = pos + delimiter.size();
    }
    if (start < s.size())
        str.push_back(s.substr(start));

    for(auto &elem : str)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/r4wvrS)

Comment: I see the method you are proposing and it seems to align with the question well, but the compiling is giving me the error `'cout' is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: @Feynman137 add `#include <iostream>`

Comment: How would one access say the first entry in the vector?  I am trying `String elem = str.at(1);` and `String & elem = str[1]`;  not sure why this is failing.

Comment: @Feynman137 like arrays, vector indexes start at 0, not 1. Make sure the vector is not `empty()` before accessing it

Comment: Looks like I needed to say `std::string zzz = str.at(0);` instead of `String zzz = str.at(0);`

Answer (score -1):

TRY this:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Suites
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class StringLabelAdapter
{
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> firstLabelFound;
public:

StringLabelAdapter(std::string& stringPassedIn, std::string& delimiter):firstLabelFound()
{
    int arrayIndex = 0;

    size_t delimiterPosition = 0, prevDelimiterPosition = 0;

    while ((delimiterPosition = stringPassedIn.find( delimiter, prevDelimiterPosition)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string token = stringPassedIn.substr(prevDelimiterPosition, delimiterPosition);
        if (!Exists(token))
        {
            firstLabelFound[token] = prevDelimiterPosition + 1;
        }
        prevDelimiterPosition += token.size() + delimiter.size();
    }
    };

    bool Exists(std::string& labelToCompare) { return firstLabelFound.find(labelToCompare) != firstLabelFound.end(); };
    };
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(TestStringLabelAdapterSuite)
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestStringLabelAdapter)
    {
    std::string stringPassedIn = "scott>=tiger>=mushroom>=fail";
    std::string delimiter = ">=";
    StringLabelAdapter test(stringPassedIn,delimiter);
    std::string s("scott");
    BOOST_CHECK(test.Exists(s));
    }
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

if you don't want boost unit test remove the boost header and the boost suite and put it in main.